# Associative Arrays in @requestparam

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am completely new to spring mvc. Please excuse me if this is asked already

**Problem**
A user can have multiple contact details. Each contact detail will have it's own form. For eg phone number -> 1 text box; address -> 3 text boxes

In PHP I used to do

```
<input type="text" name="contact[0][type]" value="PHONE">
<input type="text" name="contact[0][number]" value="456">
<input type="text" name="contact[1][type]" value="ADDRESS">
<input type="text" name="contact[1][address1]">
<input type="text" name="contact[1][address2]">
<input type="text" name="contact[1][address3]">
```

and my `$_POST` array will contain everything formatted into different associative arrays.

Can I do something similar in Spring ?

**Update**
I been on this for a couple of days and I have tried a few things including List, Map, Properties. I have also modified the name of the input fields. No luck.
For the domain Objects I successfully did the following

```
class User {
//..
Set<ContactDetails> details;
}

abstract ContactDetails{}
class Phone extends ContactDetails {}
class Address extends ContactDetails {}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327019/how-do-i-pass-this-js-array-to-my-mvc-3-controller

Comment: I have seen that question already. That talks about serializing the data. I am trying to send form data