# Ajax call hits with null values

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a array and I get data from the array and going to pass it to the controller through ajax call.
But the problem is it hits the controller side with all the null values.(Data not passes,null passes )

Client Side Code

```
for (var j = 0; j < NewsGlobalArray.length; j++) {  
    var NewsRequestModel = {
        DESCRIPTION: NewsGlobalArray[j]['DESCRIPTION'] // news description comes here.i checked it with console.log
     }}

    $.ajax({
        url: $('#addNewsRequest').val(),
        type: "POST",
        data: { newsRequest: NewsRequestModel },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (referenceNo) {
            //success
        }
    });
}
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddNewsRequest(NewsRequestModel newsRequest) // hits here with null values
{
    //Some coding goes here.
}
```

My Model

```
public class NewsRequestModel 
{
    public int NEWSREQUESTID { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please open your browser's console and paste the JSON you're sending to the server.

Comment: Also your properties seem angry, for whatever reason. :D

Comment: Aand you should also add `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",` to your ajax call.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917255/c-sharp-web-method-is-not-calling-in-javascript/27917333#27917333

Comment: @iuliu.net it hits the contoller with null values

Comment: Maybe this helps? -> `data: JSON.stringify({ newsRequest: NewsRequestModel }),` instead of `data: { newsRequest: NewsRequestModel },`

Comment: what is the value of the js variable NewsRequestModel?

Comment: You loop is just creating a new `NewsRequestModel` each iteration so you  only ever get the last one. What are you actually trying to do with this? And its just `data: NewsRequestModel` if you just want to post back the last value

Comment: Show us the JSON you are sending please

Answer (score 0):

Try this: just add **traditional:true** in ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $('#addNewsRequest').val(),
        data: JSON.Stringify({ newsRequest: NewsRequestModel }),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional:true,
        success: function (res) {
           //do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: @TechGuy Please refer following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327019/how-do-i-pass-this-js-array-to-my-mvc-3-controller/37072244#37072244

Comment: `traditional` is for sending arrays, but OP is only sending one object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to this:

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject.name = "John";
myObject.age = 12;
```

then pass `myObject` to ajax call and get on controller by name.

Comment: check by console.log(NewsRequestModel) on browser.